# How do I use Powerline-compatible fonts in Windows / PuTTY?

Tags: windows, fonts, putty, powerline-statusline

###### My putty terminal-session with Courier New fonts doesn't render some Powerline glyphs (such as the powerline `>` glyph) correctly.  How can I add a new Powerline-compatible font into Windows?

I'm using Windows10 with [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) version 0.77.

[image: not_using_powerline_font]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### 1. Choose a new font from [the known Powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)

###### 2. Download the new powerline-compatible True-Type font(s) in a temporary folder and select them.

[image: Powerline_fonts_selected]

###### 3. Right-click over fonts and select "Install for all users"

[image: Install_fonts_for_all_users]

###### You may need to reboot to use the new fonts.  Enjoy your improved Powerline experience.

[image: Powerline_with_compatible_fonts]

---

FYI, this is my [powerline-shell](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell) configuration in linux...  I had to use `mode: 'patched'` to render the powerline glyphs correctly.

From `~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json`...

```
{
  "mode": "patched",
  "segments": [
    "virtual_env",
    "aws_profile",
    "ssh",
    "cwd",
    "git",
    "git_stash",
    "jobs",
    "set_term_title",
    "svn",
    "newline",
    "root"
  ],
  "cwd": {
    "mode": "patched"
  },
  "theme": "default"
}
```

---

NOTE: This is my [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) configuration... as you can see, I configured [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) to use the  [DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/DejaVuSansMono) font.

[image: PuTTY > Window > Appearance]

Be sure [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/)'s "Remote character set" is set to *UTF-8*.

[image: PuTTY > Window > Translation]